# Sum, multiple two increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

if {$x_n$}and {$y_n$} strictly  increasing ,then  {$x_n+y_n$}and {$x_n×y_n$ }strictly increasing.

Is it true? If not why

If {$x_n$}and {$y_n$} monotonic  ,then  {$x_n+y_n$}  monotonic?

False , if $x_n=3n$ inc. and monotonic   a, $y=-n $ dec. and monotonic 
$x_n+y_n= 2 $   so, either inc. and non dec.

Can anyone help me because I'm a bit confused

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n=x_n+y_n$

Then $b_n=x_n+y_n <x_{n+1}+y_{n+1}=b_{n+1}$

Now for the second:

Take $x_n=y_n=-\frac{1}{n}$ which are both strictly increasing.

Then $x_ny_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

$(x_{n+1}+y_{n+1})-(x_{n}+y_{n})=(x_{n+1}-x_{n})+(y_{n+1}-y_{n})>0$, now $x_{n}=-1/n$, $y_{n}=n$ are both strictly increasing but $x_{n}y_{n}=-1$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

For the sum

$$(x_{n+1}+y_{n+1})-(x_n+y_n)=$$
$$=(x_{n+1}-x_n)+(y_{n+1}-y_n)> 0$$

the sum is increasing.

For the product.

with $x_n=n+1$ and $y_n=\frac {-1}{n+1} $,

we get $$x_n \times y_n=-1.$$